# copy GL_TEXTURE_2D into one slice of a GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY Texture

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to copy one GL_TEXTURE_2D into a chosen slice of a GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY Texture.

I try to bind the usual Texture_2D to one framebuffer and only a slice of the Texture_2D_Array to another framebuffer (both have the same size (width, height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)).
Afterwards I thought to `glBlitFramebuffer` would copy that texture into this one slice... but I think I misunderstand the `glFramebufferTexture3D` command.

BTW: the GL_TEXTURE_2D is loaded correctly and I also printed it out (works)

**Here my code:**

```
//Create 2 FBOs for copying textures
glGenFramebuffers(1, &nFrameBufferRead); //FBO for texture2D
glGenFramebuffers(1, &nFrameBufferWrite); //FBO for one slice of the texture2d_array
CBasics::GetOpenGLError(); 

//generate the GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY with given values (glgentextures is already called for this texture)
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, GL_RGB, nWidth, nHeight, countSlices, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
CBasics::GetOpenGLError();  

//Bind the Texture2D to the readFramebuffer
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, nFrameBufferRead);
glFramebufferTexture(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, texture2D_ID, 0);
CBasics::GetOpenGLError();

//try to bind the Texture2D_Array to the drawFramebuffer
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, nFrameBufferWrite);
CBasics::GetOpenGLError(); //till here everything works (no glerror)
glFramebufferTexture3D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, texture2D_Array_ID, 0, slicenumber); // here the error appears 
CBasics::GetOpenGLError();

//because of the error one step earlier here will be the next error... 
glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, nWidth, nHeight, 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
CBasics::GetOpenGLError();
```

at `glFramebufferTexture3D` the error appears: GL_INVALID_VALUE
I think it is because of

> GL_INVALID_VALUE is generated if texture is not zero or the name of an
>   existing texture object.

1st: Is this way to copy textures into arrayslices correctly? Or is there a better way to do that?

2nd: Is it possible to bind only one slice of a GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY?

3rd: Do I need the `glFramebufferTexture3D` command or the `glFramebufferTexture2D` command for GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAYs?

Comment: Are you actually trying to *copy* the data, or do you want to render to that array layer? Because these are two *very different* operations.

Comment: @NicolBolas I am trying to copy the data... after this method inside the TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY the one slice should be the TEXTURE_2D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that "Here's my code" actually does contain all of your code, it doesn't work because you didn't bind the 2D array texture before calling `glTexImage3D` to allocate storage for it.

However, you don't have to render or blit to copy texture data. You can copy texture data by... [copying texture data](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture_Storage#Texture_copy). The `glCopyImageSubData` function can copy layers between textures with different array layer counts. In your case:

```
glCopyImageSubData(
    texture2D_ID, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    texture2D_Array_ID, GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, 0, 0, slicenumber,
    nWidth, nHeight, 1);
```

This requires OpenGL 4.3 or better, or one of the ARB/NV_copy_image extensions. The NVIDIA extension is actually quite widely implemented.

But you still need to use `glTexImage3D` correctly.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer! the glCopyImageSubData works! there is just one mistake inside: the last parameter must be '1' instead of '0'. Thx a lot!